# how to implement slider in exjts without css

Tags: extjs, slider, extjs3, section508

Using ExtJS,

```
new Ext.slider.MultiSlider({
        renderTo: 'multi-slider-horizontal',
        width   : 214,
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 100,
        values  : [10, 50, 90],
        plugins : new Ext.slider.Tip()
    });
```

now this will display slider, but my requirement is to make it work when css is turned off?
trying to make it compliant to section 508.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have your working example, I will use the [demos I found](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/slider/slider.html). It seems as though *none* of the sliders on that page get keyboard focus, therefore you have bigger issues than making it work without CSS.

As a work around I would probably recommend you putting a compliant text box next to the slider so that somebody could use the text box to update the slider.